# Let S be the set of all 8 -bit strings (a sequence of 1s and 0s)...

Tags: functions

[image]

---

So I understand that (i) in that it would be f(10000001)=0 as there are two 1's. However I dont understand the reasoning I should put forward for the (ii) and (iii).

For (ii) my thought is that there is only 0 and 1 which can be the output then it would be an onto function because for all Y(0 and 1) there does exist an X which is the set of binary numbers possible.

Comment: An onto function is one that takes on all elements of the codomain as values. What's the codomain here? Is every element of the codomain a value of $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were off to a good start with (ii) in recognizing that all of the possible outputs were $0$ and $1$.  However, you need to also notice that the codomain of the function is $\mathbb Z$, the set of all integers.  If the function were given as $f:S\to\{0,1\}$, then it would be onto.  However, since there are many many integers that are not possible outputs of $f$, the function that was given is not onto.

To determine if the function is one-to-one, you need to investigate whether it is possible for two different inputs to the function to have the same output.  That's definitely the case for this function, so $f$ is not one-to-one.  To demonstrate this formally, all you need to do is to show two different inputs that have the same output and you're done.